# How to make a curve cross a line more than once?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to create a graph such as this one:

[image]

I don't know how to create the red line that you see in case 1 so that it will cross the blue line more than once.

Here is what I got so far.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} % To plot almost everything.
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc, patterns, positioning, shapes.geometric, decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\scriptsize

\draw (0,0) -- (3.3,0);
\draw (0,-0.75) -- (0,3);
\node [right] at (3.3,0) {$m$};
\node [left] at (0,3) {};
\draw [blue] (0.05,2.75) to [out=270,in=180] (3.2,-0.2);
\draw [fill] (0.155,2) circle [radius =0.05];
\draw [fill] (0.52,1.2) circle [radius =0.05];
\draw [fill] (1.1,0.55) circle [radius =0.05];
\draw [fill] (1.8,0.11) circle [radius =0.05];
\node [below] at (1.9,-1) {\small Case 1};

\draw [xshift=5.1cm] (0,0) -- (3.3,0);
\draw [xshift=5.1cm] (0,-0.75) -- (0,3);
\node [xshift=4.1cm][right] at (3.3,0) {$m$};
\draw [xshift=5.1cm,blue] (0,1.8) to [out=290,in=180] (3.1,0.05);
\node [xshift=4.2cm,blue,above] at (3.1,0.0) {$u_2$};
\draw [xshift=5.1cm,red] (0,2.83) to [out=290,in=182] (3.1,0.55);
\node [xshift=4.2cm,red,above] at (3.1,0.5) {$\gamma u_1$};
\node [xshift=4.1cm, below] at (1.9,-1) {\small Case 2};

\draw [xshift=10.2cm] (0,0) -- (3.3,0);
\draw [xshift=10.2cm] (0,-0.75) -- (0,3);
\draw [xshift=10.2cm,red] (0,1) -- (3,1);
\node [xshift=8.2cm,red] at (3.3,1) {$\gamma u_1$};
\draw [xshift=10.2cm,blue] (0,2.5) to [out=290,in=170] (3.1,0.15);
\node [xshift=8.2cm,blue,above] at (3.1,0.15) {$u_2$};
\draw [xshift=10.2cm,fill] (1.03,1) circle [radius =0.05];
\node [xshift=8.2cm][right] at (3.3,0) {$m$};
\node [xshift=8.2cm,below] at (1.9,-1) {\small Case 3};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already specifying the points at which the red curve is to intersect with the blue one. So you could simply use them in a curve.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\scriptsize

\draw (0,0) -- (3.3,0);
\draw (0,-0.75) -- (0,3);
\node [right] at (3.3,0) {$m$};
\node [left] at (0,3) {};
\draw [blue] (0.05,2.75) to [out=270,in=180] (3.2,-0.2);
\draw [fill] (0.155,2) circle [radius =0.05];
\draw [fill] (0.52,1.2) circle [radius =0.05];
\draw [fill] (1.1,0.55) circle [radius =0.05];
\draw [fill] (1.8,0.11) circle [radius =0.05];
\draw [red] (0.05,2.75) to [out=270,in=180] (0.155,2)
to[out=0,in=90] (0.52,1.2) to[out=-90,in=180] (1.1,0.55) to[out=0,in=90] 
(1.8,0.11) to[out=-90,in=180] (3.2,-0.2);
\node [below] at (1.9,-1) {\small Case 1};

\draw [xshift=5.1cm] (0,0) -- (3.3,0);
\draw [xshift=5.1cm] (0,-0.75) -- (0,3);
\node [xshift=4.1cm][right] at (3.3,0) {$m$};
\draw [xshift=5.1cm,blue] (0,1.8) to [out=290,in=180] (3.1,0.05);
\node [xshift=4.2cm,blue,above] at (3.1,0.0) {$u_2$};
\draw [xshift=5.1cm,red] (0,2.83) to [out=290,in=182] (3.1,0.55);
\node [xshift=4.2cm,red,above] at (3.1,0.5) {$\gamma u_1$};
\node [xshift=4.1cm, below] at (1.9,-1) {\small Case 2};

\draw [xshift=10.2cm] (0,0) -- (3.3,0);
\draw [xshift=10.2cm] (0,-0.75) -- (0,3);
\draw [xshift=10.2cm,red] (0,1) -- (3,1);
\node [xshift=8.2cm,red] at (3.3,1) {$\gamma u_1$};
\draw [xshift=10.2cm,blue] (0,2.5) to [out=290,in=170] (3.1,0.15);
\node [xshift=8.2cm,blue,above] at (3.1,0.15) {$u_2$};
\draw [xshift=10.2cm,fill] (1.03,1) circle [radius =0.05];
\node [xshift=8.2cm][right] at (3.3,0) {$m$};
\node [xshift=8.2cm,below] at (1.9,-1) {\small Case 3};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also removed all unnecessary packages and Ti*k*Z libraries. And I am wondering about two things. First, you are using `xshift` very much. Personally I'd use scopes. Second, how did you get those points on the first curve? It might be much easier to get them with `decorations.markings`.

Comment: With respect to your questions, about `xshif` I must admit I am just inheriting an old template that I never questioned, I will, however, take into account your suggestion. Also, the points were assigned randomly, so they could be anywhere. If you could give me more info regarding `decorations.markings` I would appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a plot with explicit formula and place a bit of sine on it. Thenyou can use intersections library to find the crossings.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (3.3,0);
\draw (0,-0.75) -- (0,3);
\node [right] at (3.3,0) {$m$};
\node [left] at (0,3) {};
\draw [red, thick] plot[domain=0.:2.5, samples=41] (\x,{-0.2+2*exp(-1.5*\x)});
\draw [blue] plot[domain=0.:2.5, samples=101] (\x,{-0.2+2*exp(-1.5*\x+0.2*sin(10*\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would use `pgfplots` instead for these diagrams.

Comment: I need two things that this code does not provide. First, the blue line must be non-increasing. Second, it can never cross the X-axis, as in the graph. I don't know whether this is possible to do just with the sin function.